# $include in a C++ file, and other $ values in the code

Tags: c++

I have recently been given a sizeable chunk of legacy C++ code which I want to move to the latest VS2012 compiler or the GCC compiler.

When I look at some of the files however, I can see some items of code prefixed with a $ sign.

For example I have some include lines:

```
#include "utlString.h"
$include "gclFloat_c.h"
```

and an enum declaration:

```
$enum gclEFormatType
{
    StandardFormat = 0,         // e.g. 192784.272674700000000000
    ScientificFormat = 1,       // e.g. 1.927842726747E5          (includes exponent)
    ExtendedFormat = 2          // e.g. 1.927842726747E5S30       (includes exponent and significant digit count)
};
```

and I have some other declarations:

```
$cointerface [dual] gclIFloat : IDispatch 
{
  ...
}

$coclass [STA] gclCFloat;
```

I think they may be pre-processor macros, but I'm not sure. Can anyone tell me what there are and how are they used?

Thanks

Comment: Is that preprocessed before being fed to the preprocessor?

Comment: That's not standard C++. Perhaps the build process uses its own preprocessor, or a compiler with funky language extensions.

Comment: It doesn't look like the code is pre-processed. The code is the same before and after the builds. I was wondering if its a UNIX specific thing, as we do use the same code to build on UNIX and WIN32.

Comment: @Nick: Preprocessing isn't going to modify the file; it will create a temporary processed file that's discarded after compilation. No, it's not a Unix-specific thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

- The code is run through some external preprocessor before being fed to the compiler;
- It's some compiler-specific extension (check your compiler's documentation); or
- It's a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like the code is going through an IDL pre-processor, possibly for ATL, which is injecting COM code directly into the source. I can see the intermediary files in the build output, which has a lot more code than the original file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those files are intended to be parsed to generate include files for both c++ and a scripting wrapper, like swig, but the [dual] and [sta] make me think it's targeting C# as the second language.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be Visual Studio [nmake syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx).

You can find many tutorial about this on the internet, the dollar sign is also used as an identifier for tokens with a [Visual Studio specific syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ( outside nmake ).

Comment: I don't see anything in the nmake description that talks about `$include`. There's a `!INCLUDE` syntax, but that would be in a Makefile, not in C++ source. Can you link to something more specific? And Microsoft's compiler permits dollar signs in identifiers, but that doesn't imply that `$include` is a valid preprocessing directive. `$include` is definitely not standard C++ (or C) preprocessor syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson I honestly think that is something related to Visual Studio, the official documentation of VS talks here and there about the ability to create tokens with the `$` sign; I also think that the best way to solve this is to ask on the MSDN forum since it's the right community for this.